# I am working on CRUD using firebase's fireestore in React, and I made a button to delete the data, but there is a problem

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I tried writing code with Stack Overflow and googling, but it doesn't work normally

I'm trying to use a method that allows the data to be deleted from the **DB of firestore** when I click the delete button, but there's a problem

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Parent Components**

```
export default function MyCart() {
  const [cartProd, setCartProd] = useState([]);
  const [uid, setUid] = useState(null);

  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    setUid(user.uid);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const getProd = async () => {
      const q = query(collection(db, "users", "user", `${uid}`, "userBasket", "basket"));
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const docProd = { ...doc.data() };
        setCartProd((product) => [...product, docProd]);
      });
    };
    getProd();
  }, [uid]);

return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-3xl mx-20 mt-24 mb-3 font-semibold">장바구니</h1>
      <section className="flex mx-12">
        <article className="w-8/12">
          {cartProd && (
            <ul>
              {cartProd.map((item) => (
                <CartProduct key={item.id} product={item} />
              ))}
            </ul>
      ...
```

**Child Components**

```
export default function CartProduct({ product }) {
  const { name, price, category, size, quantity, imageUrl } = product;
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const handleClick = () => navigate(`/products/${product.id}`, { state: { product } });

  const [uid, setUid] = useState(null);
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    setUid(user.uid);
  });
  const deleteBasketItems = async () => {
    const q = query(doc(db, "users", "user", `${uid}`, "userBasket", "basket", `${product.id}`));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    for (const docSnpshot of querySnapshot.docs) {
      await deleteDoc(docSnpshot.ref);
    }
  };
  const handleDelete = () => {
    deleteBasketItems();
  };
      ...
```

Comment: Your document path looks correct. But the `onAuthStateChanged` method should be in the useEffect hook as follows : ```useEffect(() => 
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setUid(user.uid);
    });
    return () => unsubscribe(); 
  }, []); ```

Comment: I tried using the sample code snippet for document deletion and it worked fine. Have you tried logging the docs your getting from the query first? You should see something like: fh {converter: null, _key: ht, type: 'document', firestore: vh} The query might be broken or doesn't return any documents.

Comment: hi does my comment helped ?